# iOS apps - are users automatically notified of new versions

Tags: ios

What are, if any, the requirements my app should obey to ensure users get notified that an update is available? (For what it is worth, my current app is freeware)

Comment: Yes, users are automatically notified...your requirements are 1. Upload the updated app 2. Wait

Comment: give some more details regarding it, as well.. This is veryy less to give any help about..

Comment: @borrrden Thanks. I just was not entirely sure if there could be situations where I was required to do more than that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are notified automatically via the App Store, and starting with iOS 7, updates are even installed automatically by default.